# error - could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error stating *`could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments`*

here is my code :

```
    var lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if -lastContentOffset > 64 { // *could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments*
        //do something
    }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
var lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
if (lastContentOffset * -1) > 64 {
    //do something
}
```